# Mac OS, Java Splash

Tags: java, macos, splash-screen

I'm trying to immigrate my Java application to Mac OS.
When the application start, splash screen supposed to appear.

When i running the App from the terminal it go like this:

`java -classpath /the/right/classpath/ -splash:images/splash.png myApp/Main`
when i do like this the splash screen appears.

But when i bundle the App with the
 [Jar Bundler](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Java/Conceptual/Jar_Bundler/Introduction/Introduction.html), the splash screen does not appear.

on the Jar Bundler, under the properties tab, in the VM Option i wrote:
`splash:images/splash.png`
I also tried:
`-splash:images/splash.png`(with hyphen).
I marked the option "*Set Working Directory To Inside Application Package"* as well.

i copy the `images/splash.png` to :

myApp.app/Contents

myApp.app/Contents/Resources

myApp.app/Contents/Resources/Java

myApp.app/Contents/MacOS

But the splash screen refuses to appear!

It's strange because the myApp.app succeed to run - it just not show the splash screen.

I found at the console this two messages:

> Feb 11 02:53:32 SnowL /Users/myusername/Desktop/myApp.app/Contents/MacOS/JavaApplicationStub[24262]: Unrecognized Java VM option ignored: -splash:images/splash.png

This without hyphen before the splash attribute.

> Feb 11 02:55:50 SnowL  /Users/myusername/Desktop/myApp.app/Contents/MacOS/JavaApplicationStub[26314]: Unrecognized Java VM option ignored: splash:images/splash.png

How it can by that when i run the app from the terminal the splash screen appear,
but double click on the App does not show the splash screen?

it supposed to run on the same VM like the terminal VM, doesn't it? 
I olso change the JVM version (on the Info.plist file) to: 
1.5* 
1.5+ 
1.6* 
1.6+ 
none of them make the splash screen to appear.

Thanks for help!

Comment: After looking at the link for 'Jar Bundler' I cannot see anything that it can do that cannot be achieved using Java Web Start (http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  Can you distribute the app. from a server?

Comment: I'm not so familiar with the java web start (good time to learn it :) 
I can install form web start but can't run from web start.
Anyway the JVM should be the same JVM, right?

So make you think that with Web Start the splash screen appear?

Does the Web-Start run from a different JVM?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like this, in your Info.plist:

```
...
<key>Java</key>
    <dict>

    <key>MainClass</key>
    <string>...</string>

    <key>SplashFile</key>
    <string>$APP_PACKAGE/tmp_splash.png</string>
...
```

Comment: why mac bundled app ignores MANIFEST.MF ?

Answer (score 3):

In my application:
Info.plist:

```
    ...
    <dict>
        <key>ClassPath</key>
        <string>$JAVAROOT/@PROJECTNAMEASIDENTIFIER@.jar:@CLASSPATH@</string>
        <key>JVMVersion</key>
        <string>1.6+</string>
        <key>MainClass</key>
        <string>@PROJECTMAINCLASS@</string>
        <key>SplashFile</key>
        <string>$JAVAROOT/splash.png</string>
    ...
```

Copy **splash.png** to **myapp.app/Contents/Resources/Java/splash.png**
et voila.

Answer (score 1):

You could make your application show a jFrame with decorations off and your picture at the start up of the application

Comment: The whole idea of splash screen is that the user see something while  the App id loaded.
if i use jFrame, the JMV need to load it - its increases the loading time, and that's exactly what I did not want to happen.
I read some tutorials that offer this way of programing - i think that is not the right way to do it. Anyway, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and found a solution on this thread:

http://lists.apple.com/archives/java-dev/2008/Jun/msg00012.html

It involves adding an entry to the bundled application's Info.plist file after using Jar Bundler. Also, the image needs to be copied to myApp.app/Contents/Resources/Java (at least with the "set working directory inside application package" option). There's probably a better way, but this seems to work.