# Building java application with BuildDesk - Adding splash screen path

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, awt, splash-screen

I have application developed on netbeans which have splash screen implemented with java splash screen API. I can run it perfectly in netbeans(By setting vm option as -splash:image/splash.png). Also i can run it by running jar too. 
Problem is my partner use [BuildDesk](http://www.productiveme.com) to bundle application. After building application with that it won't work. I set additional vm options too. But then it gives following error.

```
Unrecognized Java VM option ignored: -splash:image/splash.png
```

Is there anyone got this problem before me? I've seen someone got this problem with JarBundler [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964397/mac-os-java-splash). Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: What version of java does BuildDesk build against? -splash was added in Java 6, so I would make sure that BuildDesk actually supports that version.

Comment: @firelore Seems they haven't release a new version after 2009, Can you suggest how to find whether or not builddesk support to splash screen?

Comment: I haven't used BuildDesk myself, but a quick look into their download shows it uses ant 1.6.5 to build and it mentions Java 1.4 in some of their examples. Ant should still be able to use JDK 6 for compiling, so it may be either your partner's installation being too old or BuildDesk overriding things. If you need a splashscreen, either change build tools or use mKorbel's solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Seems they haven't release a new version after 2009, Can you suggest how to find whether or not builddesk support to splash screen?

- for all `>JDK 1.4` you can to create undecorated `JDialog`, better `JWindow`
- put there required contents, `JComponents` or `image` and/or with `text` e.g.
- on App's start to show `Old_schools SplashScreen`,
- if all required code ended, then call `JDialog / JWindow#setVisible(false);` and then show App's window
- if is there `SplashScreen` only for `whatever reason`(s), then to use `Swing Timer` (`Timer#repeats(false);`)