# Splash screen for bundled Java-App on macOS

Tags: java, macos, bundle, splash-screen

I am trying to show a Splash-Screen on a bundled Java-Application under macOS.
The JAR-File does contain a splash-image itself and does show it when launched by console or by double-click. As stated in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964397/mac-os-java-splash), the Java-native splash screen is ignored and must be defined in the Info.plist file.
I've tried to declare a `SplashFile` directly as well as passing the `-splash` option to the VM. To make sure that I didn't have a wrong relative path, I placed the splash-file at every folder level within the bundled application. Still it won't show up.

My Info.plist looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.8">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>DummyScreen</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>DummyScreen</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1.0 (Test)</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleAllowMixedLocalizations</key>
    <string>true</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>DummyScreen</string>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>English</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
    <string>CTD.icns</string>
    <key>Java</key>
    <dict>
        <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
        <string>$APP_PACKAGE/Contents/</string>
        <key>MainClass</key>
        <string>DummyScreen</string>
        <key>JVMVersion</key>
        <string>1.8+</string>
        <key>SplashFile</key>
        <string>$APP_PACKAGE/CTD.png</string>
        <key>Arguments</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>VMOptions</key>
        <string>-Djava.security.policy=./no.policy -splash:CTD.png</string>
        <key>ClassPath</key>
        <array>
            <string>$APP_PACKAGE/Contents/DummyScreen.jar</string>
            <string>$JAVAROOT/</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Other attributes stated in the file are applied correctly (e.g. the application gets the desired icon and shows the correct version-number), only the splash-screen refuses to show. Any other approaches than those stated in the mentioned thread? Or can anybody find a mistake in my Info.plist?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is likely to be lying in my compiled *JavaApplicationStub* which i copied from one bundle to another. It must somehow not support the `SplashFile` Tag.

Solved it by adopting a new *JavaApplicationStub*, more precisely the [UniversalJavaApplicationStub](https://github.com/tofi86/universalJavaApplicationStub)